# Why must malloc be used?

Tags: c, variables, memory, memory-management, malloc

From what I understand, the malloc function takes a variable and allocates memory as asked. In this case, it will ask the compiler to prepare memory in order to fit the equivalence of twenty double variables. Is my way of understanding it correctly, and why must it be used?

```
double *q;

q=(double *)malloc(20*sizeof(double));

for (i=0;i<20; i++)
{
    *(q+i)= (double) rand();
}
```

Comment: The `malloc` function does not "take a variable". It takes as argument the required memory size, and returns as result a freshly allocated (unaliased) memory pointer zone.

Comment: No need to typecast malloc in ANSI/ISO C, for more read this :http://c-faq.com/malloc/cast.html

Comment: typecasting malloc means this... `(double *)`...correct? Do we not add this anymore because newer versions of C can recognize that we are already dealing with a `double` instead of a `char`?

Comment: @EngGenie: no version of C has ever required that cast, but people's coding styles have varied. CERT used to advise that the cast be included as a security measure. Now they advise that the cast *never* be used because it's a security risk (and that's the common view I think -- the cast introduces more risk of coding error than it removes). Go figure.

Comment: @SteveJessop: On an ICL Perq in the early 1980s, the cast was necessary (crucial).  The machine was microcoded and used 32-bit addresses to 16-bit words.  There was no `void *` type.  The `char *` type used some high-order bits in the address to indicate that (a) it was a byte address and (b) whether it was the odd or even byte that was addressed.  If you assigned a `char` pointer to an 'anything else' pointer, it was crucial that you included the explicit cast.  That included converting the value returned by `malloc()` et al.  Omitting that cast crashed your program reliably.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: rats, that's what I get for assuming that just because someone slaps the label "C" on something, it will bear some vague resemblance to the language Ritchie invented ;-)

Answer (score 6):

You don't have to use `malloc()` when:

1. The size is known at compile time, as in your example.
2. You are using C99 or C2011 with VLA (variable length array) support.

Note that `malloc()` allocates memory at runtime, not at compile time.  The compiler is only involved to the extent that it ensures the correct function is called; it is `malloc()` that does the allocation.

Your example mentions 'equivalence of ten integers'.  It is very seldom that 20 `double` occupy the same space as 10 `int`.  Usually, 10 `double` will occupy the same space as 20 `int` (when `sizeof(int) == 4` and `sizeof(double) == 8`, which is a very commonly found setting).

Comment: Ah it seems I mixed up the pointers in my notes ! I meant to say it will allocate memory for 20 `double`. Thank you for the excellent answer!

Comment: @EngGenie: If you see an answer that answers your question, it's usually a good idea to *accept* it ie. clicking the grey tick-mark on its left. This gives the answerer some extra points and serves as a hint to others who read your question.

Answer (score 4):

It's used to allocate memory at run-time rather than compile-time. So if your data arrays are based on some sort of input from the user, database, file, etc. then `malloc` must be used once the desired size is known.

The variable `q` is a pointer, meaning it stores an address in memory. `malloc` is asking the system to create a section of memory and return the address of that section of memory, which is stored in `q`. So `q` points to the starting location of the memory you requested.

Care must be taken not to alter `q` unintentionally. For instance, if you did:

```
q = (double *)malloc(20*sizeof(double));
q = (double *)malloc(10*sizeof(double));
```

you will lose access to the first section of 20 `double`'s and introduce a memory leak.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the heads up on memory leaks!

Answer (score 3):

When you use `malloc` you are asking the system "Hey, I want this many bytes of memory" and then he will either say "Sorry, I'm all out" or "Ok! Here is an address to the memory you wanted. Don't lose it".

It's generally a good idea to put big datasets in the heap (where `malloc` gets your memory from) and a pointer to that memory on the stack (where code execution takes place). This becomes more important on embedded platforms where you have limited memory. You have to decide how you want to divvy up the physical memory between the stack and heap. Too much stack and you can't dynamically allocate much memory. Too little stack and you can function call your way right out of it (also known as a stack overflow :P)

Answer (score 1):

In you example, you could have declared `double q[20];` without the `malloc` and it would work.

`malloc` is a standard way to get dynamically allocated memory (`malloc` is often built above low-level memory acquisition primitives like `mmap` on Linux).

You want to get dynamically allocated memory resources, notably when the size of the allocated thing (here, your `q` pointer) depends upon runtime parameters (e.g. depends upon input). The bad alternative would be to allocate all statically, but then the static size of your data is a strong built-in limitation, and you don't like that.

Dynamic resource allocation enables you to run the same program on a cheap tablet (with half a gigabyte of RAM) and an expensive super-computer (with terabytes of RAM). You can allocate different size of data.

Don't forget to test the result of `malloc`; it can fail by returning NULL. At the very least, code:

```
 int* q = malloc (10*sizeof(int));
 if (!q) {
    perror("q allocation failed");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
 };
```

and *always initialize* `malloc`-ed memory (you could prefer using `calloc` which zeroes the allocated memory).

Don't forget to later `free` the `malloc`-ed memory. On Linux, learn about using [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/). Be scared of [memory leaks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak) and [dangling pointers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer). Recognize that the liveness of some data is a non-modular property of the entire program. Read about [garbage collection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29)!, and consider perhaps using [Boehm's conservative garbage collector](http://www.hpl.hp.com/personal/Hans_Boehm/gc/) (by calling `GC_malloc` instead of `malloc`).

Comment: Excellent answer, exactly what I was looking for thank you! Does one test the results of `malloc` like this? ... `if (p==NULL)
    {
        printf("Can not allocate requested memory for p\n");
    }`

Comment: Better use `perror` to display the failure reason thru `errno`

Comment: Seems you beat my question before it was asked by an answer, hah !

Answer (score 1):

As the others said, malloc is used to allocate memory. It is important to note that malloc will allocate memory from the heap, and thus the memory is persistent until it is `free`'d. Otherwise, without malloc, declaring something like `double vals[20]` will allocate memory on the stack. When you exit the function, that memory is popped off of the stack.

So for example, say you are in a function and you don't care about the persistence of values. Then the following would be suitable:

```
void some_function() {
    double vals[20];
    for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        vals[i] = (double)rand();
    }
}
```

Now if you have some global structure or something that stores data, that has a lifetime longer than that of just the function, then using malloc to allocate that memory from the heap is required (alternatively, you can declare it as a global variable, and the memory will be preallocated for you).

Answer (score 0):

You use `malloc()` to allocate memory dynamically in `C`. (Allocate the memory at the `run time`)
You use it because sometimes you don't know how much memory you'll use when you write your program.
You don't have to use it when you know thow many elements the array will hold at compile time.

Another important thing to notice that if you want to return an array from a function, you will want to return an array which was not *defined* inside the function **on the stack**. Instead, you'll want to dynamically allocate an array (on the **heap**) and return a pointer to this block:

```
int *returnArray(int n) 
{
    int i;
    int *arr = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * n);
    if (arr == NULL) 
    {
        return NULL; 
    }

    //...
    //fill the array or manipulate it
    //... 

    return arr; //return the pointer
}
```

Comment: Down voted: I think it is better style if the caller of the function provides the memory.

Comment: Yes, the caller of the function is usually not interested in HOW things are done in the function. But still better style to provide the memory that shall be filled.